# how to change woocommerce shop archive description?

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I use elementor to show dynamics text based on product categories description.

I can change categories description from woocommerce, but how can I change the default shop page description? "This is where you can browse products in this store."

thanks.

Comment: WooCommerce, Elementoor and other 3rd party plugin/theme dev support is off topic and not in this stacks scope. You should ask via their official support routes or in their groups and communities.

Comment: @memeyou Did you find an answer? I would also like to know.